# Find the first word of a paragraph inside a list

Tags: python, list, paragraph

I have created a list that contains a different paragraph inside each element.

I want to find the first word of each paragraph.

The only thing I can come up with is to split each paragraph in to individual words and find `element[0]`. This seems fairly excessive as I already have each paragraph already in the list

So what is a better way to do this?

Comment: You're right that fully splitting each paragraph just to retrieve one word feels wasteful; is there something you're going to do with the paragraphs later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
l = ['start of paragraph 1','start of paragraph 2','para 3']
first_words = [p.split()[0] for p in l]
print first_words
```

prints: ['start', 'start', 'para']

If you don't want to split each paragraph, you could search for the index of the first space, and grab each word up to that:

```
l = ['start of paragraph 1','start of paragraph 2','para 3']
first_words = [p[:p.find(' ')] for p in l]
print first_words
```

prints: ['start', 'start', 'para']

**Explanation as requested:**

- find the first space in the paragraph with p.find(' ') - returns the position
- then take the first  characters in the paragraph via p[:p.find(' ')]
- the remainder of that line is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and basically loops through your list and takes each paragraph, `p` in turn

Comment: I think that's the one! Would you mind explaining what this part of the statement does [p[:p.find(' ')] Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you Gerrant, one filial follow up. Instead of finding the first spacem, if I wanted to find the first line break would I use find('\n') Thank you again

Comment: @captaindogface: yes...but one of the easiest ways to see is just try it!  One of the reasons Python is such a great language is that trying out things like this are so easy.

Comment: I don't like the split one, obviously you don't split the entire paragraph to only get the first word, that doesn't make sense. the find(' ') is definitely more preferable, and also the code is kept compact, which I really like. that is what is python meant to .

Comment: @zinking: You could limit the number of splits: p.split(' ', 1)

Answer (score 1):

Good grief:

```
my_paras = ["It was the best of times", "Twas a dark and stormy night", "The walrus and the carpenter"]

my_first_words = [para.split(None, 1)[0] for para in my_paras]
```

returns

```
['It', 'Twas', 'The']
```

The `None` parameter to split means 'split on any contiguous whitespace' and is usually implicit, however I have to specify it here in order to also supply the second position parameter, `maxsplit`. By passing maxsplit=1, .split() stops after it finds the first whitespace character (returning a two-item list consisting of the first word and the remainder of the paragraph) or once it hits the end of the string (returning a one-item list, the whole run-on paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each paragraph starts with a word (and not say, a space or a number):

```
[par[:par.index(" ")] for par in list_of_par]
```

This is what is called a "list comprehension". It goes through each item in `list_of_par` and applies `par[:par.index(" ")]` to it. This takes a slice of the paragraph (`par`), in this case, from the 0th character up to (but not including) the first space (`[:par.index(" ")]`).

The list comprehension returns a list of strings; each string being all the characters in the paragraph until the first space.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want your words layed out? Do you wan't to guarantee they're just not whitespace, or that they don't contain punctuation?

First cut:

```
first_words = [
        paragraph.split(None, 1)[0]
        for paragraph in paragraphs
]
```